# How to fix 'elementsFromPoint' "The provided double value is non-finite." on mobile

Tags: mobile, draggable, gsap

I get this error on the console ON MOBILE getting document.elementsFromPoint(posX, posY). On Chrome on desktop it works nice :(

```
let dragItem = Draggable.create(".drag", {
  type: "x,y",
  bounds: "#svgContainer",
  onDrag: function(event) {
      // TODO: On Mobile document.elementsFromPoint causes ERROR.
      posX = parseInt(event.clientX);
      posY = parseInt(event.clientY);
      overElement = document.elementsFromPoint(posX, posY);
      console.log(overElement);
  }
 });
```

I have this jsfiddle to show the error, emulate mobile device first with DevTools on Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/equerol/92j45hd0/21/

Answer (score 0):

You need to look back the variable of posX and posY, check it have same name somewhere, i think you need replace the name of posX and posY to other name